# RAILS: Authlogic gem & Userstamp plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I have an application that uses the [*Authlogic* gem](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/tree/master) and needs the functionality 
of the [*Userstamp* plugin](http://github.com/delynn/userstamp/tree/master).

AFAIK *Userstamp* works very well with [*RestfulAuthentication*](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master), though I couldn't find anything mentioning using it together with *Authlogic*.

Has anyone of you tried to combine them? Are there issues I should be aware of? Should I use a completely different plugin/gem to get the functionality of *Userstamp* in combination with *Authlogic*?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just found it out the hard way. ;-)

If you use Authlogic (2.0.11) in combination with Userstamp (2.0) make sure that Authlogic's `current_user` method in the ActionController is `protected` and not `private` (as is the default). Or you'll get a **NoMethodError in User sessionsController#new**.

Besides that it just works like a charm.

P.S.: There's no need to manually implement the `set_stamper` method in the ActionController. Authlogic and Userstamp work well with the method defined by the Userstamp plugin. If you've no idea what I'm talking about, just ignore this. :-)